# openshift origin - configure max pods

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm recently started working a bit with openshift and it looks promising so far, but I keep running into issues and mostly finding outdated documentation or look at the completely wrong place.

For example, I have currently an openshift installation of ~150 cores, based on a couple of servers and some of these nodes have only 4 cores and others have 48.

I would like to modify all my nodes to have pods = 1.5 * cores or so.

Is this possible?

I tried to use:

oc edit node node0

and change pods from the default 40 to say 6, but sadly oc never saves my values and always resets itself back to the default of 40.

kind regards

my openshift information:

oc v1.0.7-2-gd775557-dirty
kubernetes v1.2.0-alpha.1-1107-g4c8e6f4

installation done using ansible, single master, external dns.

Answer (score 1):

Max pods per node is set on the node - you can add in the stanza to the node config YAML file to set it:

```
kubeletArguments:
  max-pods:
  - "100"
```

The string is important - this stanza passes arguments directly to the Kubelet invocation (so any arg you can pass to a Kubelet you can pass via this config)